# Typescript conditional types not able to correctly narrow type for nested properties

Tags: typescript, type-inference, union-types, conditional-types

I encountered a strange issue. I'm wondering if this is genuine bug or just the lacklusterness of typescript's conditional types.

Consider this `interface`-

```
type EnumObj = { enm?: readonly (string | number)[] };

interface ITest {
    [key: string]: string | EnumObj;
}
```

Each property in `ITest` is either a regular `string` or an object with an optional `enm` property of type readonly array of strings/numbers. Emphasis on optional.

My goal is essentially this- For a given key in `ITest`, I need to check if the type of the value at said key is an `EnumObj` - if it is, I need to check if the type of the `enm` property within is **not undefined** (non nullable) and *then* I've to do some type deduction specifically using the value type of the `enm` property.

There's 2 levels of checks there, one to narrow the union, and one to check if `enm` is actually present.

To do this, I *thought* I could do-

```
// Nested conditional checking
type Foo<T extends ITest, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends EnumObj
    ? T[K]['enm'] extends NonNullable<EnumObj['enm']>
        ? T[K]['enm'][number]
        // ^ type `number` cannot be used to index `T[K]['enm']`
        : never
    : never;
```

That's weird, it looks like the type isn't being narrowed properly. So I tried to separate this out. Instead of 2 conditional checks to narrow down the exact type - I'll just narrow down the `enm` property, given an `EnumObj`

```
// Directly checking T['enm'] - no nesting, works fine
type Bar<T extends EnumObj> = T['enm'] extends NonNullable<EnumObj['enm']> ? T['enm'][number] : never;
```

And this works fine, as expected. So I essentially have to call `Bar` inside `Foo` to do the full type deduction. But why does the conditional types freak out for nested narrowing?

Here's the whole thing on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEFUHFQJQKIAUDycAqoC2B7LBTAOwBcAoEUAQUNBwCMArfAY2NAHcBLYgC1AEMaOAA7FOOQvwA2oIgFcsoYQCcR+ZcQCetAGagtw-KGX5+AEwlTt-Zcv7acegM7FlnQgHMnwQgrrqncjB0Hk4nDh4cKSMwpzkjQnwAN3VQHn5hQ0Jwzj0AA3ksPNAw0EIcNhExCWlQAAozOR4ASlIDIwRfLBRGUABeUABvWUIsAH4ALmNTC0Irepc3T1AAHzK-dWaAbQBdUABfAG5SINAEfmY+FTUNbXd9HhiSdR0LmPD+UDlCcRp20ncxBeb1AAEl0PgXENSKBYaAtgBrfCaKaLdweHao1zo1ZnLo9BjHfYnCgAOUhQLMoGYEjM3F+tUuLAR6NO7VAeS6-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)

Another weird part is, even though `Foo` gives error. I can actually use it `Foo<{ f: { enm: [1, 2, 3] } }>` and it will get inferred correctly.

Note that I'm not looking for *a solution* per se. I'm guessing just calling `Bar` inside `Foo` is more or less the way to go here. Note that this is a dummy example but my real goal involves nested type checking in much the same way. I'm just curious as to *why* this is happening?

Comment: Side note: simpler way to achieve the same  would be `type Foo<T extends ITest, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends { enm: ReadonlyArray<infer E> } ? E: never;`

Comment: This is probably a limitation having to do with substitution types in conditional types but I haven't found a definitely relevant issue in GitHub yet.  FWIW I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/rw2nrw) might be a [mcve] for this situation

Comment: @jcalz Hmmm, the substitution for conditional types does seem very lackluster. I'm surprised there's not an issue for it.

Comment: I think it does a pretty good job in a lot of use cases, but issues remain and will probably always remain.  I still can't find an applicable existing issue (there are near misses, though) so it's possible someone (you?) might want to open one to get clarification, but I'd expect the answer to be "this is a design limitation" or even "this is working as intended because you can work around it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/QmbO9W)".

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I expect the answer to be "not a bug" as well. But I do believe better narrowing on conditional types is on the ts team's list judging by the many issues related to the conditional type substitution. In the mean time, forcefully extracting/picking the expected type seems like a pretty good solution!